# date comparison not working properly in shell script

Tags: shell, date, cron, ksh

I want to compare dates in shell script.
The logic I am using as below :

```
$date_1="Tue Nov 25 23:50:01 CST 2014"
$date_2=$(date)
if [ $date_2 -eq $date_1 ] ; then
      echo "$date2 is equal to $date_1"
else
      echo "$date2 is not equal to $date_1"
fi
```

However when I am executing the script using `crontab` for every minute,
I got the below message in log which is not correct :

> Tue Nov 25 23:50:01 CST 2014 is not equal to Tue Nov 25 23:50:01 CST 2014

Could you please help me out of this embarrassing situation?

Comment: Also how current value of date can be equal to a static value of date?

Comment: I have kept the date_1 as a future date value statically and schedule this scripts in crontab for every minute. so as soon as the dates matched, it will give the output but unluckily it is not happening here

Comment: Anubhava: it's a good point ... but you can predict hours, minutes, seconds, no ? Agreed it's a bit weird, but in a logical way, it makes sense. You know what day it'll be tomorrow, no ?

Comment: Abuzar: I'm suspecting there's whitespaces or special characters involved. When you print the variable, surround them with something, like : echo "+${date_1}+ +${date_2}+" - I don't know if { and } work in Korn, but I think they do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this job is running every minute. You can do:

```
date_1="Tue Nov 25 23:50:01 CST 2014"

dt1=$(date -d "$date_1" '+%Y%m%d%H%M')

dt2=$(date '+%Y%m%d%H%M')

if [ "$dt1" -eq "$dt2" ]; then
      echo "$dt2 is equal to $date_1"
else
      echo "$dt2 is not equal to $date_1"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Best thing would be to format your date strings to look like numbers, starting with year, then month, etc.  You probably would want to code a greater than or equal, or less than or equal, in case cron skips a second now or then:

```
date_1=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
sleep 10
date_2=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
if [ $date_2 -ge $date_1 ] ; then
    echo "$date_2 is greater than or equal to $date_1"
else

    echo "$date_2 is less than $date_1"
fi
```

Output:

```
20141126063044 is greater than or equal to 20141126063034
```

Beware you don't want the `$` in front of the variable when you are setting it!